# Is optstring in getopt case sensitive?

Tags: getopt

Would the `v` below parse `-V` options as well?

```
getopt -o v
```

Is it even possible to parse uppercase command options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer to your question - getopt is case sensitive ,  generally it is not recommended to use different cases in script arguments - it can create confusion

you can think of using multichar inputs in it .

Try and read about getopt  --longoptions.

Refer below example for the same.

```
# Read command line options
ARGUMENT_LIST=(
    "input1"
    "input2"
    "input3"
)



# read arguments
opts=$(getopt \
    --longoptions "$(printf "%s:," "${ARGUMENT_LIST[@]}")" \
    --name "$(basename "$0")" \
    --options "" \
    -- "$@"
)


echo $opts

eval set --$opts

while true; do
    case "$1" in
    --input1)  
        shift
        empId=$1
        ;;
    --input2)  
        shift
        fromDate=$1
        ;;
    --input3)  
        shift
        toDate=$1
        ;;
      --)
        shift
        break
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

and this is how you can call the script

```
myscript.sh --input1 "ABC" --input2 "PQR" --input2 "XYZ"
```

try this , hope this was useful